# Executing "systeminfo" cmd command WaitForExit doesn't continue

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, console-application

I try execute systeminfo cmd commnand and I have a problem. My problem is that when it comes to method WaitForExit(), the program doesn't continue. I try

```
        using (var cmd = new Process())
        {
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            cmd.Start();
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("systeminfo");
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();

            cmd.WaitForExit();

            var result = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            cmd.StandardOutput.Close();

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following options:

Option 1:
Subscribe to Process.Exited event and when the systeminfo process exits, read the stream to get the result of the process.

Option 2:
Redirect the systeminfo process output to a text file. When process exists event occurs, read the result from the text file.

also instead of cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("systeminfo"); pass the systeminfo process as the argument. It will provide you more control.
ex: cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C systeminfo.exe";

Answer (score 3):

Is there a particular reason you go through `cmd` here? That's so utterly unnecessary here and also explains your problem. You run an interactive instance of `cmd`, pretending as if you typed `systeminfo` and then wait for `cmd` to exit. Just as a normal interactive instance, it won't do that. It will just sit there, waiting for more commands. Instead, why not just call `systeminfo` directly?

```
    using (var systeminfo= new Process
      {
        FileName = "systeminfo",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
        UseShellExecute = false,
      })
    {
        systeminfo.Start();

        var result = systeminfo.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        systeminfo.WaitForExit();

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I had the same issue, only I was not starting CMD, but systeminfo directley. 
I was only experiencing the issue on a Windows 7 PC, not on Windows 10.

Like JulioEnrique I was reading StandardOutput after WaitForExit()
Moving the wait after the StandardOutput.Read fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must add command to cmd, cmd run that and return results and exit.
Use command like "cmd /c ver" works fine and return windows version.